# ActiveRecord query where all associations included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

As an example, let's say I've got these three tables:
Event, Attendance (Join Table), and User.

```
Event has_many attendances and has_many users through attendances
User has_many attendances and has_many events through attendances
Attendance belongs_to attendance and belongs_to user
```

I'd like to be able to query all Events to find where x users all attended.
As an example:

```
Event     | Users who attended Event
1               [1, 3, 4, 6, 9]
2               [1, 4, 9]
3               [3, 4, 6]
4               [2, 3, 6]
```

I want to say
`Event.by_attendended_users(user_4, user_9)` and get
`Events: [1, 2]`

I was thinking something along the lines of `joins(:attendances).where("attendances.user_id IN :user_ids")` or something similar, but haven't quite got it to work as desired yet. Any help or feedback is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: As a couple of additional details, as @AbM pointed out,  <s>if the join is only ever on 2 users at once, there is a little hack that can be used to find the users.</s>  The solution doesn't work because the second part of the query is over-writing the first part.

Ideally, this should be able to work on any number of associations, although the bare minimum requirement only says that it needs to use 2. (for now)

Additionally, I'd like to be able to use this as a scope, meaning it can be chained onto other scopes to filter down further. The solution by @AbM would work with this only if that scope was called first in the chain of other filters.

Comment: @AbM - Very clever! Optimally, I would like to account for a situation that used more than 2 users, but that's the bare minimum requirement right now, so if there isn't a better solution, I will happily use this one. :) Thank you!

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. I think the `where(attendances: {user_id: user_9.id})` is over-writing the initial scope and landing back to the original problem. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
user_ids = [4, 9]
events = Event
user_ids {|user_id| events = events.where(id: Event.joins(:attendances).where(attendances: {user_id: user_id})) }
events
```

Another way you can do that is with a custom count:

```
user_ids = [4, 9]
Event.joins(:attendances).having('COUNT(CASE WHEN attendances.user_id IN (?) THEN 1 END) = ?', user_ids, user_ids.length).group(:id)
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for one user to have multiple attendances to the same event, as the search results get jumbled by the count. But it's a good start. I may just do the rest of it manually using regular array manipulation.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Why would one user have multiple attendances to the same event?

Answer (score 0):

```
user_ids = [1, 3, 5]
events = Event.joins(:attendances)
user_ids.each {|user_id| events = events.where('attendances.user_id = ?', user_id) }

# events now contains all events where all specified users attended
```